# Object inheritance in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I am trying to extend a class using typescript in angular and I am having this error:

```
 export class Product {

  constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string,
     public brand?: string, public expiry?: Date) {

  }
}

export class StockItem extends Product {
  constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string,
     public brand?: string, public expiry?: Date, public category?: string,
     public price?: number, public quantity?: number,
     public sold?: number, public description?: string,
     public status?: boolean, public expired?: boolean,
     public addedOn?: Date)

      super(id, name, brand, expiry);
}
```

The error line:

```
src/app/models/data.model.ts(96,6): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
src/app/models/data.model.ts(96,28): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
src/app/models/data.model.ts(97,6): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
src/app/models/data.model.ts(97,31): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
src/app/models/data.model.ts(98,6): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
src/app/models/data.model.ts(99,6): error TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
```

Comment: brackets are missing no ? on your stockitem constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `{}` for the constructor body which should contain the call to super:

```
export class Product {

constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string,
    public brand?: string, public expiry?: Date) {

}
}
export class StockItem extends Product {
    constructor(id?: number, name?: string,
        brand?: string, expiry?: Date, public category?: string,
        public price?: number, public quantity?: number,
        public sold?: number, public description?: string,
        public status?: boolean, public expired?: boolean,
        public addedOn?: Date) {

        super(id, name, brand, expiry);
    }
}
```

Also no need to redeclare the fields declared by the base class (ie, I removed the `public` modifier, from `id`, `name`, `brand` and `expiry` since they are already declared in the base type).